# Get a value form Object

Tags: php, arrays

I have this object and I need to echo the value of ...attributes->pa_unidaddeventa

```
WC_Product_Variation Object
(
    [post_type:protected] => product_variation
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [pa_unidaddeventa] => 11-70cmx100m
                    [pa_manipulacion] => 56-cortadaa62_8cm
                )

...
```

The variable `$product` contains the object. I tried with these but not working. It should print out this value: `11-70cmx100m`

```
echo $product->data[1]->attributes[1]->pa_unidaddeventa;

echo $product->data[0]->attributes[0]->pa_unidaddeventa;
```

**Both prints nothing. What is the mistake?**

Comment: What if you use `['pa_unidaddeventa']` instead of `->pa_unidaddeventa`? Does that do the trick?

Comment: @TijnvdEijnde it does not, I get an error blank page.

Comment: When you `echo $product->data[1]` you will get a result right?

Comment: Also I think `11-70cmx100m` should be a string `"11-70cmx100m"` and could you show me the error you are getting?

Comment: You should learn the difference between array and object. `$product->data['attributes']['pa_unidaddeventa']`. `$product` is an object with a property `data` which is an array containing an array.